# Parsed between list of two dates for each client Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with sales which is looks like this:

```
id   date         cost
a   2019-01-04  -1350.0
b   2019-01-04  7500.0
b   2019-01-04  17800.0
c   2019-01-04  17750.0
d   2019-01-04  1179.0
```

And I need to get information for each client with their sales before 1 year since they did last order.
I took clients only for this year and get date before 1 year like this:

```
client['last_order'] = pd.to_datetime(q['last_order'])
client['year_ago'] = client['last_order'] + pd.DateOffset(years=-1)
```

And get:

```
last_order  cost       id    year_ago
2020-08-09  2215.00     a   2019-08-09
2020-08-07  4361.00     b   2019-08-07
2020-08-08  30113.50    b   2019-08-08
2020-06-06  270.00      b   2019-06-06
2020-08-04  64495.07    a   2019-08-04
```

Then I have to get information for each client's sales only between two dates.
I tried to use something like this:

```
orders = sales[(sales['date']<=client['year_ago'])&(client['date']>=q['last_order'])&(sales['id']==client['id'])]
```

But I get a mistake:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Then I tried another way:

```
for cust, d1, d2 in zip(client['id'], client['year_ago'], client['last_order']:
     sales = sales.append({'client':cust, 'date1':str(d1), 'date2':str(d2)}, ignore_index=True )
```

But it doesn't work too.
Also the df with sales containes 68 million lines

Comment: There is no sample data for `sales` ?

Comment: @jezrael  it is in first code's frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df = sales.merge(client, on='id')
orders = df[(df['date']<=df['year_ago'])&(df['date']>=df['last_order'])]
```